# Terminal browsing, macros, and where to ask these kinds of questions

Tags: terminal, macros

I know this is going to be closed immediately because its not the type of question thats meant to be asked here. BUT, BEFORE YOU DO, can you please let me know a good place to ask these kinds of questions? OK so here it goes:

I'd like to learn how to do the following: browse the internet from terminal (on mac), and be able to automate certain web based tasks. For example, log into a given site, traverse to a given page and download a table into a text file.

Now, I'm not asking for anyone to tell me exactly what to do, but I'd like to know how to get stared with learning that type of thing. By all means, close this question, but please let me know where is a good place to ask.

Comment: [How to Surf the Web in Terminal](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_surf_web_terminal), and [Scheduling Timed Jobs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) is what you looking for?

Comment: Yea those are great starts thanks a lot! But also, is there any other place to ask these kinds of questions? I know that on stack you're supposed to have like an exact computation problem with code versus "How do I" questions...